# How to convert int format to string format when defining python programs

Tags: python, python-2.7, type-conversion

I want to convert my input from int to string but i cannot do it! This is my code! Please help!

```
 def hi(x):

       print x
```

if I put a letter for x,an error message comes! I don't want to give my input within double quotation marks.without doing that, is there any way?

Comment: Could you please be a little clear? Can you give some examples

Comment: Where does the error message come, and what is the error message ?

Comment: For an example, if i type hi(klmnop) , it would give an error message like "klmnop is not defined" !

Comment: Rule of Python #1, built-in methods are used for typecasting. `str(x)`

Comment: @TharushiGeethma Unfortunately this is a duplicate.

Comment: I can't put it like hi(str(x)) because this is a defined program code!

Comment: It's hard to say without seeing the entire program, but I have a feeling the real answer is "use `raw_input` instead of `input`"

Answer (score 1):

Its quiet simple.

```
def hi(intx):
   target = ''.format(intx)
   print target
```

Comment: Yea but that does not mean that your question was clear. This is indeed a duplicate questions and the moderators are right about that.

Answer (score 1):

```
def hi(x):
    print(type(x))
    x= str(x)
    print(type(x))
```

So your argument is an integer but when you do `str(x)`, you change the data type to string.